# EF Lazy Loading, extraction of query to another method results in null for navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I am using Entity Framework and have a model that Access Control Listings are applied to. I have a One-To-Many relationship between my Model and the ACL Model.

In a majority of place that I need to query my model, I only need to return the models which have a corresponding ACL.

Here is an example:

```
var myUnits = _context.Units
    .Include(unit => unit.AccessControlRules)
    .Where(unit => unit.AccessControlRules.FirstOrDefault(acl => acl.UserId == 15) != null);
```

This works correctly every time. It will only return units that have an acl for the user with Id 15.

However, when I extract this into the following form, it throws a value cannot be null exception because unit.AccessControlRules is null.

```
    var myUnits = _context.Units
    .Include(unit => unit.AccessControlRules)
    .Where(unit => permissionCheck(unit));

    private bool permissionCheck(Unit unit)
    {
        return unit.AccessControlRules.FirstOrDefault(acl => acl.UserId == 15) != null;
    }
```

It's the exact same code, whereas the second (non-working) version `unit.AccessControlRules == null`.

Could someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Why are you using "===" instead of "=="?

Comment: Beat me to it @Matt

Comment: @Matt bloody js

Comment: Note you are not using lazy loading, but eager loading instead.

Comment: Quick note: instead of `unit.AccessControlRules.FirstOrDefault(acl => acl.UserId === 15) != null` you can use `unit.AccessControlRules.Any(acl => acl.UserId === 15)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that in the permissionCheck method the child objects haven't been loaded yet due to EF not knowing how to create an appropriate SQL query for the function (or something like that).

You *could* do it by adding `.AsEnumerable()` after the `Include` and before the `Where` BUT this will mean that you load ALL Unit and Rule objects from the DB into memory before you apply the where clause and so will, probably, use more memory and time - and, hence, likely not be an efficient way to query things.